# How to include javascript, which is dependent on an external library, to a page rendered by a custom module?

Tags: 8, javascript

**Edited**

I want to draw an SVG circle on my page with [d3.js](https://d3js.org/). I have constructed a skeleton custom module and I am returning the following render array from *src/Controller/MyModuleController.php*:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

class MyModuleController {
  public function myModule() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => '<div id="data-vis"></div>',
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' =>  array(
          'social_statistics/circle',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In my *libraries.yml* (located in the root of my module folder) I have:

```
circle:
  js:
    circle.js: {}
    dependencies:
      - social_statistics/d3

d3:
  remote: https://d3js.org
  version: 4.x
  license:
    name: BSD
    url: https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js: { type: external, minified: true }
    # d3.min.js: { minified: true }
```

In *circle.js*, (also located in the root of my module folder) I have:

```
d3.select("#data-vis")
  .append("svg")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 30)
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("r", 20);
```

I'm getting the below error in the console, which suggests circle.js is being loaded, but not the d3 library dependency?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Comment: If you include the dependency in libraries.yml for circle.js, then you should not need to attach d3 in the render array.

Comment: You need to reference the library in the pattern `module/library` see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/167372/42650 and https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module

Comment: I've made some changes - see above - and `circle.js` is loading, but not the d3 library dependency - any ideas?

Comment: Answer: the issue is in libraries.yml - the indentation is wrong!